# Storekit and handling users who have already purchased IAPs

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, subscription, storekit

I was following [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/154737/app-purchases-auto-renewable-subscriptions-tutorial) RW tutorial, and as with a lot of IAP and `Storekit` tutorials, they talk about the flow of the user purchasing the IAP for the first time, but they don't elaborate on how the app operates when a user who has already purchased the IAP opens the app again.

Updating my question as I found the key to the problem:

as far as I can tell the code that blocks/displays the content is a lookup for (1) the receipt and (2) a `SessionID` …he doesn’t go into any detail in the tutorial what the SessionID is for or whether it’s only as part of the demo for the tutorial.  For example it only gets set when `uploadReceipt` is called (which only get’s called when `handlePurchasedState` or `handleRestoredState` are called).  In other words, if a user opens the app already having a subscription, there’s no code running to set the `SessionID` so the content is never unlocked?

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SubscriptionService.shared.loadSubscriptionOptions()
    return true
  }  
}


// MARK: - SKPaymentTransactionObserver

extension AppDelegate: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

  func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue,
                    updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    for transaction in transactions {
      switch transaction.transactionState {
      case .purchasing:
        handlePurchasingState(for: transaction, in: queue)
      case .purchased:
        handlePurchasedState(for: transaction, in: queue)
      case .restored:
        handleRestoredState(for: transaction, in: queue)
      case .failed:
        handleFailedState(for: transaction, in: queue)
      case .deferred:
        handleDeferredState(for: transaction, in: queue)
      }
    }
  }

  func handlePurchasingState(for transaction: SKPaymentTransaction, in queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    print("User is attempting to purchase product id: \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
  }

  func handlePurchasedState(for transaction: SKPaymentTransaction, in queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    print("User purchased product id: \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")

    queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
    SubscriptionService.shared.uploadReceipt { (success) in
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: SubscriptionService.purchaseSuccessfulNotification, object: nil)
      }
    }
  }

  func handleRestoredState(for transaction: SKPaymentTransaction, in queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    print("Purchase restored for product id: \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
    queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
    SubscriptionService.shared.uploadReceipt { (success) in
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: SubscriptionService.restoreSuccessfulNotification, object: nil)
      }
    }
  }

  func handleFailedState(for transaction: SKPaymentTransaction, in queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    print("Purchase failed for product id: \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
  }

  func handleDeferredState(for transaction: SKPaymentTransaction, in queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    print("Purchase deferred for product id: \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be notified of purchases every time the user launches the app, though technically you could validate the app receipt and reprocess every IAP every time the program runs. That seems inefficient. Your app should just keep track of what has been purchased as it is purchased.

If the app is ever removed and re-installed, or if the user installs it on another device, you should provide a "Restore In-App Purchases" function that refreshes the app receipt and validates it.

Comment: Thank you...as I said though I'm specifically using a subscription IAP, so not only do I need to know if it was purchased, but I need to know if it has expired...so I'm trying to figure out the best approach?